# Does a websocket upgrade still allow http ajax requests?

Tags: http, websocket

When an http connection is upgraded to a websocket connection can my javascript code still use http ajax GET requests for example? That is, I can do both normal http requests and websocket messages or does "upgraded to websocket" mean the http capabilities are gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server supports both normal web requests and WebSocket upgrades (some servers are either one or the other), then you can continue to make AJAX requests even while you have a WebSocket connection. AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) requests are just regular HTTP/HTTPS requests that are initiated by Javascript rather than by the browser when the page loads. Having an active WebSocket connection will not interfere with other HTTP/HTTPS (or AJAX) connections. Unless of course the server has a bug.